# If there's an error in an R loop, return NA or zero and continue with the loop

Tags: r

I'm building an R Shiny App and it gets very cumbersome when errors are introduced. I have a dataframe and I am looping through the rows using an NLS function and returning the EC50 value. The EC50 are then added to the original dataframe to display. Not every observation will fit so it returns an error and the app breaks.

What I would like is a way to return a NA or 0 when there are errors and for the loop to move on to other observations. A simple example of the code would be

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = rep('hi',3))

addition <- function(a,b){
  result <- a+b
  return(result)
}

df$z <- 1
for (i in 1:length(df$x)){
  df$z[i] <- addition(df$x[i], df[i,i])
}
```

The results I would like is as below:

| x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | hi | 2 |
| 2 | hi | NA |
| 3 | hi | 6 |

This is just a sample. What I'm doing is more complicated but I want to return NA/0 with any types of error, and since it's user uploaded files, I wouldn't be able to know which index the error is going to be in.

Comment: A few comments: (1) The example you give based on the sample data is not reproducible. Please provide representative sample data and a function that simulates the error and/or return arguments that you are expecting from your real function. The devil is in the detail here; us trying to guess what the real function does on your end is not the fastest way to solve your issue. (2) Looping through rows in the way you do is awkward and slow. Better to `Vectorize` your function and then operate on whole `data.frame` columns directly; or use a `mapply`/`Map`/`purrr::map2`/`purrr::pmap` construct

Comment: @MauritsEvers I think the OP is asking how to return an NA when a function that is supposed to return a single number throws an error as part of a loop (whether or not the loop is disguised as a vectorized function or map/apply type function). Getting a single EC50 from an `nls` fit is mentioned in the question, and this is certainly a good example of a situation where such a scenario might occur. I agree though that without more information we can't assume this is the most efficient approach.

Comment: Ah yes. Thanks for clarifying @AllanCameron. I think you're right, in which case `tryCatch` is the way to go (+1). I'd still get rid of that `for` loop and use `Vectorize` (or something similar); true, it's a loop in disguise but more "R canonical".  Or better perhaps, have a `list` and then `Map` entries. Row-wise `data.frame` operations always bother me ;-)

Comment: Sorry guys. I tried beforehand but found it hard to replicate valid nls() or drc() models or curves with random data. I totally agree that Map() and apply() are better than for loops in R but just haven't gotten to learning it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `tryCatch` here. When an error is caught, it can simply return an `NA`; otherwise it returns the result of the calculation:

```r
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3), y = rep('hi',3))
df$z <- 1

for (i in 1:length(df$x)){
   df$z[i] <- tryCatch(
    addition(df$x[i], df[i,i]), 
    error = function(e) return(NA)
    )
}

df
#>   x  y  z
#> 1 1 hi  2
#> 2 2 hi NA
#> 3 3 hi  4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>